# Circle loader with checkmark - How to add an X failure state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How would I go about adding an failure state with an X instead of an tick to the following? I don't really get how the tick is generated.

The jquery and html is no problem just the actual generation of the tick and how this would be altered to display an X.

```
<div class="circle-loader">
      <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>

<p><button id="toggle" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Toggle Completed</button></p>

    body {
    padding: 5em;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

// Define vars we'll be using
$brand-success: #5cb85c;
$loader-size: 8em;
$check-height: $loader-size/2;
$check-width: $check-height/2;
$check-left: ($loader-size/6 + $loader-size/12);
$check-thickness: 2px;
$check-color: $brand-success;

.circle-loader {
      margin: 0 0 30px 10px;
      border: $check-thickness solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      border-left-color: $check-color;
      animation-name: loader-spin;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
}

.circle-loader,
.circle-loader:after {
     border-radius: 50%;
     width: $loader-size;
     height: $loader-size;
}

.load-complete {
     -webkit-animation: none;
      animation: none;
      border-color: $check-color;
      transition: border 500ms ease-out;
 }

 $('#toggle').click(function() {
       $('.circle-loader').toggleClass('load-complete');
       $('.checkmark').toggle();
 });
```

https://codepen.io/scottloway/pen/zqoLyQ

Comment: You are leaving out vital CSS in your example. The tick is generated using CSS, defining green borders for an element and then rotating that element. If you wanted to do this with an X in the same way you would need to write the proper CSS for it. Alternatively, there are [similar codepens](https://codepen.io/elevaunt/pen/JYRBzJ) that already have the feature to create checkmarks and X's using CSS.

Comment: That similar one uses SVG. I just copied and pasted the css from the code pen example.

Comment: Yes sorry I did not have my morning coffee yet, I meant to say SVG. It is also possible to draw the X using CSS, I would suggest using the `:after` psuedo-element to do this.

Comment: I know to use the :after its the actual drawing of it i dont get.